# How to solve relashionship automaticly generated by infyom

Tags: php, laravel-5

I try to use scaffold from table of relational-object database using `infyom` but i can't manipulate object like in POO because the models generated contains only the id of the other object! there is a way to manipulate object correctly?

model generated is like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

/**
 * Class Facture
 * @package App\Models
 * @version July 17, 2018, 6:08 pm UTC
 *
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Consomme
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection contient
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection EstFactureBst
 * @property \App\Models\EstFacture estFacture
 * @property string num_facture
 * @property date date_facture
 * @property string etat_facture
 * @property integer num_releve
 */
class personnel extends Model
{

    public $table = 'personnel';

    public $timestamps = false;
    public $sousPersonnel;


    protected $primaryKey = 'id_pers';

    public $fillable = [
        'id_pers',
        'lib_pers'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'lib_pers' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [

    ];

    public function SousPersonnel(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\TypePersonne::class);
    }
}
```

there is a relation between my class personnel and `TypePErsonne` but when I want to write like `$personnel->typePersonne` and make dd I have it null I use `Eloquent ORM` it seems like they can't find `typePersonne` for my object `$personnel`

Comment: Please improve this question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ids does not follow the Laravel standards I have to add the id in the relationship after the class

> ```
> public function SousPersonnel(){
>    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\TypePersonne::class, 'sous_pers_id');
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined relation within the method named `SousPersonnel()` so to read it you should use `SousPersonnel` attribute like this:

```
$personnel->SousPersonnel
```

Comment: I read the documentation of relation between models So what I should do is to add the foreign_key in the relation because my primary key in the other model is not like 'id' or 'model_id' so i should do that    public function SousPersonnel(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\TypePersonne::class, 'id_type_pers);
    }.
But now when I want to see all of typePersonne it return only one. what shoud I do?

Comment: Trying to access `$personnel->SousPersonnel` should return [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#available-methods). To get all records as an array you should use `$personnel->SousPersonnel->all()`

Comment: I tried both and both give only a collection or a aray of a first sousPersonnel and I look at my database I have three type corresponding to this personnel what should I do?